# Rewrite url in browser

Tags: .htaccess, url

Hi how do I rewrite URL in `.htaccess`?

```
localhost/app/view/login/editPass.php
```

to

```
localhost/editPass.php?
```

when I come from my index

```
localhost/index.php
```

I know I have to use, something like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)
```

So do I need to have the `.htaccess` file with my index or in the folder app?

Answer (score 0):

The `.htaccess` should be on the parent directory. `RewriteRule ^/editPass.php?$ app/view/login/editPass.php`
 It must have the `RewriteEngine On` On top first. The "RewriteRule" line is where the magic happens. The line can be broken down into 5 parts:RewriteRule - Tells Apache that this like refers to a single RewriteRule.

```
^/editPass.php?$
```

- The "pattern". The server will check the URL of every request to the site to see if this pattern matches. If it does, then Apache will swap the URL of the request for the "substitution" section that follows.

  app/view/login/editPass.php

  - The "substitution". If the pattern above matches the request, Apache uses this URL instead of the requested URL.